# R - Derivative of a function F(x)

Tags: r, derivative

I've some troubles deriving functions in R. Given a function g(x,y) (I give a simplified example of a and b here) I define

```
a <- Vectorize(function(x) -x^2/2)
b <- function(x,y) x*sin(y)
g(x,y) <- function(x,y) exp(a(x))*b(x,y)
F <-  Vectorize( function(y) {integrate(function(x) g(x, y), lower = 0, upper = 1, subdivisions=30000000)$value})

f <- Vectorize(function(x) deriv( function(x) CDF(x), namevec = "x") )
```

but it doesn't work. I did a workaround doing

```
h = 0.000001
f <- Vectorize(function(x) (F(x+h)-F(x))/h)
```

but I'm worried it is not very precise.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this RPubs post](https://rpubs.com/venkatritch/333327)?

Comment: @RuiBarradas interesting, tho I guess the problem here is that F(x) is not an expression cause it is the result of an integration!

Comment: You're right, R can't derive that function. R is not the best tool for symbolic computation, can't you compute the derivatives you need by hand?